# Thymeleaf couldn't resolve a specific template only when running in a Docker container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, thymeleaf

In my spring-boot application i have a simple controller like this:

```
public Class MyController(){

    @GetMapping("/gioca")
    public String viewQuiz(Model model){
        //stuff
        return "gioca";
    }
}
```

The template, `gioca.html`, is under resources/templates/, like the others.

No error shows while executing the app from IDE or command line (I've tried both `mvn exec:java` and `java -jar app.jar` after creating the jar file).

All seems fine, but when I create a Docker container that specific template stop working, giving me the following exception:

```
 ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-10] Exception processing template "gioca": Error resolving template [gioca], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [gioca], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
...
ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [gioca], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [gioca], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

while all the other templates work just fine.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:18-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I tried to re-creating both the jar file and the container, rename the template, change the path but nothing worked.

Comment: Did you configure anything regarding thymeleaf / templateresolvers yourself? The full resource path is `src/main/resources/templates/gioca.html`? And `public Class MyController(){` is actually `@Controller public class MyController {`? (like in e.g. https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-template-directory which also has some tips regarding not found errors)

Comment: No, i didn't configure anything about template resolvers. The path is correct. And yes the controller has its annotation (In that controller there are other method that works).

Comment: Besides spelling errors (HTML/htm/html?) including strange things like hidden zerowidth utf8 spaces and other strange utf8 characters, you can also check if there is anything wrong with the file permissions ("not accessible"). But it seems odd because in a jar that would load template resources via classpath it should behave identical in docker and outside. When it's loading them as files (I think in mvn exec) it could in theory see a difference due to case insensitive filesystems (win/mac) vs on a linux server where that matters. Have you tried a copy of that file with a different name?

Comment: I forgot to delete an old docker image... It was a very stupid error.
Thanks for the help anyway.